# store monthly date into array from the selected date

Tags: php, date, datetime

Assume that selected date from Canlender is 02/09/2011. To store weekly date into array from 20/09/2011 is

```
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
{
    $WeeklyDate[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(2011-09-02) - 86400*$i);
}
```

My question is how to store monthly date into array from the selected date.

Many thanks

**---Update----------**

The final result of monthlyDate should look like the following:

```
$monthlyDate= array{2011-08-03, 2011-08-04, 2011-08-05, 2011-08-06, 2011-08-07 ....2011-08-31, 2011-09-01, 2011-09-02}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the number of days in a month using [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) and then proceed as you are doing with weeks eg:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 9, 2011);

for($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++)
{
   $MonthlyDate[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(2011-09-02) - 86400*$i);
}
```

Notice that `CAL_GREGORIAN` is a built-in constant.

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/h4AT75x2)

Comment: The codepad link does not provide the desired output.  The code in the answer yields `FATAL ERROR Invalid numeric literal` on the `$MonthlyDate[]` line.  Please edit or remove it so SO readers are not confused by it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever programs are incrementing a date using `86400` there is a risk of unexpected output because of DST.

By using `strtotime()` with a unit larger than hours (like days, weeks, months, etc.) preventing any DST hiccups.  Note: a DateTime object approach *can be* used but for this case, it is unnecessary overhead.

The following is an adjusted form of a [one-liner date range function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array/42558584#42558584) I developed.

Here is the [online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c6aaec0ec0e24676bb0da5d7f184c36f8229fe3) for this case.

```
function getDatesFromRange($a,$b,$x=0,$dates=[]){
    while(end($dates)!=$b && $x=array_push($dates,date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$a +$x day"))));
    return $dates;
}
$date='2011-09-02';
$monthlyDate=getDatesFromRange(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$date -1 month +1 day")),$date);
var_export($monthlyDate);
```

output as desired/expected:

```
array (
  0 => '2011-08-03',
  1 => '2011-08-04',
  2 => '2011-08-05',
  3 => '2011-08-06',
  4 => '2011-08-07',
  5 => '2011-08-08',
  6 => '2011-08-09',
  7 => '2011-08-10',
  8 => '2011-08-11',
  9 => '2011-08-12',
  10 => '2011-08-13',
  11 => '2011-08-14',
  12 => '2011-08-15',
  13 => '2011-08-16',
  14 => '2011-08-17',
  15 => '2011-08-18',
  16 => '2011-08-19',
  17 => '2011-08-20',
  18 => '2011-08-21',
  19 => '2011-08-22',
  20 => '2011-08-23',
  21 => '2011-08-24',
  22 => '2011-08-25',
  23 => '2011-08-26',
  24 => '2011-08-27',
  25 => '2011-08-28',
  26 => '2011-08-29',
  27 => '2011-08-30',
  28 => '2011-08-31',
  29 => '2011-09-01',
  30 => '2011-09-02',
)
```

Comment: @Acubi If my answer sufficiently answers your question, please award it the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  If there is something not quite right, please leave a comment and I'll try to fix it up.