# Date function to display all dates between two dates

Tags: php, date

Is there any PHP function to display all dates between two dates?

Comment: No. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can you add a sample output of what you expect ? More over, what have ou tried ?

Comment: [Google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+function+to+display+all+dates+between+two+date&aq=f&oq=php+function+to+display+all+dates+between+two+date&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2j62j64.523&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). First link

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Comment: Hi FAngel: I asked any inbuild php function to calculate?

Comment: May i know why u down voted my question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is the [**`DatePeriod`**](http://php.net/dateperiod) class.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$begin = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$end = new DateTime('2013-02-13');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```

(P1D stands for period of one day, see [**`DateInterval`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) for further documentation)

Comment: Almost there - dates from 2017-11-03 to 2017-11-10 show 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09. We should either exclude 03 or include 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out this function also

```
        $day = 86400; // Day in seconds  
        $format = 'Y-m-d'; // Output format (see PHP date funciton)  
        $sTime = strtotime($start_date); // Start as time  
        $eTime = strtotime($end_date); // End as time  
        $numDays = round(($eTime - $sTime) / $day) + 1;  
        $days = array();  

        for ($d = 0; $d < $numDays; $d++) {  
            $days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)));  
        }
```

Comment: awesome stuff!!

Comment: Notice that $day = 86400; is not always correct, there are shorter and longer days when summer time is applied.

Comment: @GabrielReguly is correct, 86400 is unreliable. If you build a calendar based on 86400 seconds per day you'll even get 28 oct 2018 twice.

Comment: This does not take leap seconds into account.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $start_date  = '2020/09/01';
    $end_date    = '2020-09-03';

    $new_date = new DateTime($end_date);
    $new_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $end_date = $new_date->format('Y-m-d');

    $period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($start_date),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime($end_date)
   );

   print_r($period);
   foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
     echo $value->format('Y-m-d')  .'<br>';      
   }
```

Print: 
2020-09-01
2020-09-02
2020-09-03