# How insert only year in mysql date column

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a date that sometimes can be only a year, years and month or a full date. What is the best practice to save it on the db?

I need to do search later as: Give me all date between 2004 - 2008 or give me all date between 2004-05-21 to 2005-12-31

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date function to display all dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851190/date-function-to-display-all-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: store it as the full date. you can extract the year component as needed with `year(datefield)`

Comment: i read that i can store the date as 2004-00-00 to save an incomplete date... this could work?

Comment: @Atomico Try storing it as such and see what happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use `DATE` format (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) and then if needed use more specific functions to query records by date ranges like

```
WHERE YEAR(created) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2011
```

etc.

More date\time related functions here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Doesn't need time, so no point in storing as DATETIME. Just DATE will suffice.