# how to get all the dates in between two dates in an array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, date

I have two dates and I need all the dates in between these two dates in an array using Codeigniter. Thanks in advance for any help
I mean it like this

```
  $fromDate =$this->input->post('fromDate');
  $toDate = $this->input->post('toDate');
  $allDate = array('all the dates between these two date');
```

Comment: every nano second is a date......

Comment: can I get the days like '10/12/2013', '11/12/2013' like this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in this way.........

```
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
        $end_date =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date));
        $day = 86400; // Day in seconds  
        $format = 'Y-m-d'; // Output format (see PHP date funciton)  
        $sTime = strtotime($start_date); // Start as time  
        $eTime = strtotime($end_date); // End as time  
        $numDays = round(($eTime - $sTime) / $day) + 1;  
        $days = array();  
        for ($d = 0; $d < $numDays; $d++) {  
            $days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)));  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Venkat solution doesn't work for period that includes DST change from summer to winter time (-1 hour). Eg. for a given period from 2013-10-01 to 2013-10-31 a date of 2013-10-27 is added twice. One solution is to add one hour or 3600 seconds. So the statement in for loop is:

$days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)+ 3600));