# disable dates in jquery calendar between today's date and set date

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

I have to disable the dates between today's date to selected(set) date.
Here is my code

```
$(function () {
    $("#departure").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "+5",
         minDate: -0
    });
    $("#departure").datepicker("setDate", "5");
});
<input id="departure" />
```

here is my screenshot:-
[image]

Now I want to diable date 5 6 7 means 3 days after today.
please help me.....

Hello I got my answer perfectly,
But one issue came 
if in 5 days,if there is weekends it should be skip so what to do for that any body knows
suppose today is 11-6-2013  then 15 and 16 should be skip  and 19th date would come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer Today is 11-6-2013

```
 $("#departure").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "+1y",
         minDate: +4,
    });
 $("#departure").datepicker("setDate", "5");
<input id="departure" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are few good links which can help you:-

http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/

http://tokenposts.blogspot.ca/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

http://gauravganoo.com/tips/js/jquery-enable-disable-datepicker/

You can also use [multidatespickr](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can specify one array as range to disable like this way

```
// Disable a list of dates
var disabledDays = ["9-21-2010", "9-24-2010", "9-27-2010", "9-28-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-17-2010", "9-2-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-4-2010", "9-5-2010"];
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays
});
```

Here i am posing very useful [LINK](http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/) to disable any dates or any date range.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: is it not fixed that this much date should be disable. from today ,3 date should be disable.@liyakat

Comment: but you can assign it to javascript variable from PHP. to make one array when page is load.

Comment: suppose your selected date is before 3 days and current date you will get from date() function. find date between those days using phg and make array of string like as above in js file.

Comment: also please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array to get array of range between 2

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you please dont forget to accept and vote up. so in future for same problem. other person can easily solve it

Comment: and one more easy function to generate array with your require date format just use this : http://www.rarst.net/script/php-date-range/