# Get the days between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, days

I have a ajax data object that comers in with `$startDate` which is `Nov 12, 2013` and a `$endDate` which is `January 31, 2014` and I would like to create an array that looks like:

```
array(2013-11-12, 2013-11-13, 2013-11-14, ... , 2014-01-31);
```

The way I attempted to do this was:

```
    while($startDate < $endDate){
       $day = gmdate('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtoTime($data->data['startDate'])));
       $daysOfTheWeek[] = $day;
    }
```

But the script timed out after 30 seconds. So I am wondering what the proper way to do this is.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` But oh, that's an infinite loop. Don't crash your server

Comment: Look into the `DateInterval` class: http://us1.php.net/dateinterval

Comment: You're never changing startdate, so why do you expect it to ever be anything but less than enddate? Permanent loop

Comment: [php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Comment: If you use php 5.3 look for datetime object there is a diff method that return a datetimeinterval objet you can format with format method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $dates=array();
  $start=strtotime("Nov 12, 2013");
  $end=strtotime("January 31, 2014");
  while($start <= $end)
  {
    $dates[]=date("Y-m-d",$start);
    $start=strtotime("+1 day",$start);
  }
  print_r($dates);
?>
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/jGzr2rUB)**

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date_from = 'Nov 12, 2013';
$date_to = 'January 31, 2014';
$date_range = array_map(function ($date) {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }, iterator_to_array(
        new DatePeriod(new DateTime($date_from),
                       DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),
                       (new DateTime($date_to))->modify('+1 day'))));
var_dump($date_range);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/68133