# Count every day entry

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to count all register users each day from past 30 days. If there is no registration return `0`

Currently i'm using this

```
    $startDate = Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
    $signup = User::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
        ]);
    return $signup;
```

Current output

```
[ 
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-29",
    "value" : 1
  },
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-15",
    "value" : 1
  }
]
```

If there is no registration then display value `0` for example

```
[ 
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-29",
    "value" : 1
  },
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-28",
    "value" : 0
  },
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-27",
    "value" : 0
  },
  { 
    .....
    .....
  },
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-15",
    "value" : 1
  }
  { 
    "date" : "2014-05-14",
    "value" : 0
  }
]
```

How can I get such result.

Comment: You mean you have all that sequential dates in your table?

Comment: No, I don't have. I just have entries with date `2014-05-29` and `2014-05-15` ( For sure they are of timestamp datatype ). I want to loop through whole past 30 days

Answer (score 1):

Put the $result array in another array value by value,  and if lastrowdate - rowdate > 1 day, use this function to fill up the empty dates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312491/3696548