# How to build a dynamic html table of date with php code in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My goal is to show all the days in a table selected using a two datepicker.
Datepicker One for start date and date picker Two for end date. 
e.g 2014-08-04 to 2014-08-13.

[image]

As you can see at my table. It didn't include Saturday and Sunday and that is what im trying to achieved. Here is the code i've been playing around for a while:

```
$date1 = strtotime("2014-08-01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-08-08");

do 
{
echo date("Y-m-d", $date1)."<br>";
$date1 = strtotime("+1 day", $date1);
} while ($date1 <= $date2);
```

**Btw. I get the data populating my table using mysql and i want to manipulate it to show *saturday* and *sunday* using php and html.**

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Try this link maybe this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

So simple check day with:

```
date("N", $date1);
```

If it`s sat or sun there don`t show it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the data populating that table using mysql and i need a php code to manipulate it to show saturday and sunday as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

```
$start_date = '2014-08-01';
$start_day = date('z', strtotime($start_date));
$days_in_a_year = date('z', strtotime('2014-08-31'));

$number_of_days = ($days_in_a_year - $start_day) +1 ;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_days; $i++) {
    $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +$i day");
    echo date('d F - l', $date) .'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. What would be the output of this? What would it look like?