# Get Date and month from given year in php

Tags: php, date

I want to get date by year in php. (Ex. from 1995 to 2013). can anyone please help me on this?

01-01-1995
02-01-1995
.
.
.
.
.
31-01-2013

Comment: A year isn't a specific date. What data do you have and what do you need?

Comment: Do you mean that you need a list of all the dates in a year?

Comment: possible duplicate of **[PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21073726/67332)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is get all dates between for example 1995 and 2013. This is called a period. PHP has some nice tools to do this. For example try looking at a DatePeriod. Your code could be like this:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('1995-01-01'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2013-01-31')
);
```

This gives you a DatePeriod object that is filled with all dates using [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) so you can iterate over it using a foreach loop. The interval you need is Per 1 Day (P1D).
Next you need to fill your own array with the desired format. Like this for example:

```
foreach( $period as $date) { $array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d'); }
```

Or simply print the dates like so:

```
foreach( $period as $date) { echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "<br />"; }
```

I hope this helps. Info found at: [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)