# Display all the dates between 2 separate date column in MYsql

Tags: mysql

how can i display all dates between `start_date` and `end_date` according to the place.

**for example**.
from id 1 the result will be

> 16-10-2014
>   17-10-2014
>   18-10-2014
>   19-10-2014
>   20-10-2014
>   21-10-2014
>   22-10-2014
>   my code is not working.
>   Any help ?
>   Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: So you will pass the id and want to get all the dates in that range ?

Comment: no i like to pass the place to retrieve dates.

Comment: in mysql its pretty complicated to do it. Using the application level programming like PHP it will be very easy to do.

Comment: Any suggest how to do in PHP @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: check here how to generate the dates between 2 dates in PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array