# Loop dates between two dates using For loop then display it using foreach loop in php

Tags: php

I want to display dates between two dates in foreach loop.
Suppose the date starts May 1 2014 and ends May 3, 2014 .I want to display like this

//With for loop alone this will display what I wanted

```
for($i=$dateFrom;$i<=$dateTo;$i++) {
 echo $i."<br>";
 }
May 1,2014
May 2, 2014
May 3, 2014
```

But this code returns when using foreach loop to display it is template

```
May 3,2014
May 3, 2014
May 3, 2014
```

This is my code in action.php

```
$dateTo = $r->getParameter("date_to", date('Y-m-d'));
$dateFrom = $r->getParameter("date_from", date('Y-m-d', strtotime('7 days ago', strtotime($dateTo))));
$this->data=array();
foreach($this->deposits as $d) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->created_by = $d->created_by;
    $obj->date_created = $d->date_created;
  for($i =$dateFrom;$i <= $dateTo;$i++) {
    $date=$i;//I think the problem is here.I am not sure how to make this work
  }
  $obj->amount = $d->amount;
  $obj->dateCovered = $date;
  $this->data[] = $obj;
}
```

template.php

```
<?php foreach ($data as $i => $d): ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo ($i%2==0)?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <td><?php echo $d->id ?></td>   
            <td>
            <?php echo $d->dateCovered ?>//this will display the last date only
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php $amountTotal += $d->amount ?>
                PHP <?php echo number_format($d->amount, 2) ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $d->created_by ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("F d, Y",strtotime($d->date_created)) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

My problem here is it does not display all dates between two dates.Instead it will only display the last date between two dates.What's wrong with this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
$date_from = strtotime("1 May 2015");
$date_to = strtotime("15 May 2015");

$oneDay = 60*60*24;

for($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i=$i+$oneDay)
{
    echo date("F j, Y", $i) . "<br>";
}
```

Now you can try with this..

```
$dateTo = $r->getParameter("date_to", date('Y-m-d'));
$dateFrom = $r->getParameter("date_from", date('Y-m-d', strtotime('7 days ago', strtotime($dateTo))));

$oneDay = 60*60*24;
$date_time = strtotime($dateFrom);

$this->data=array();
foreach($this->deposits as $d) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->created_by = $d->created_by;
    $obj->date_created = $d->date_created;

    $date= date("F j, Y", $date_time);
    $date_time += $oneDay;
    $obj->amount = $d->amount;
    $obj->dateCovered = $date;
   $this->data[] = $obj;
}
```

Comment: well that will work, but I have a template that will call the action.php.Using foreach loop.Any Idea?I tried your code but it will always display the last date instead of all dates between two dates

Comment: Please try with 2nd part

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date_from = strtotime("10 September 2000");
$date_to = strtotime("15 September 2000");


$day_passed = ($date_to - $date_from); //seconds
$day_passed = ($day_passed/86400); //days

$counter = 1;
$day_to_display = $date_from;
while($counter < $day_passed){
    $day_to_display += 86400;
    echo date("F j, Y \n", $day_to_display);
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Comment: yes I know your code works but I want to do it base on my code in action.php