# PHP print date difference in numbers according too month

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates

`2016-06-22 , 2016-07-11`

I need to print the date in numbers for example,

`22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,.....11`

if the month is july to august it should print

`22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,.....11`

according to month wise also in PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Post your attempts too.

Comment: sir i have no idea how to do this, i have done upto getting the dates differences only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/BpMhC)

Comment: @Uchiha :  this could be better as expected  : https://3v4l.org/8aAmW

Comment: Thanks for ur help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you .. [Look The DatePeriod class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

A date period allows iteration over a set of dates and times, recurring at regular intervals, over a given period.

```
<?php

$begin = new DateTime( '2016-06-22' );
$end = new DateTime( '2016-07-11' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("d") . "<br>";
}
?>
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/584588)***

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate over date between start and end date and print it in format `d`.

```
$fromDate = new DateTime('2016-06-22');
$toDate = new DateTime('2016-07-11');

$days = array();
while($fromDate <= $toDate) {
    $days[] =  $fromDate->format('d');
    $fromDate->modify('tomorrow');
}

echo implode(',', $days);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
{

    // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

    // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
    // that in the main script

    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}

$arr = createDateRangeArray("2016-06-22","2016-07-11");
echo implode(",",$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

in mysql

```
select date_format(my_date_column, '%d$)  from my_table
```

in php

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-06-22');
echo $date->format('d');
```

echo the day number