# Get post status for each day from status change history

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table `post_status_changes`, which is history of post status changes

```sql
 post_id |         created_at  | status
---------+---------------------+---------
       3 | 2016-09-02 04:00:00 | 1      
       3 | 2016-09-04 19:59:21 | 2     
       6 | 2016-09-03 15:00:00 | 5      
       6 | 2016-09-03 19:52:46 | 1      
       6 | 2016-09-04 20:53:22 | 2
```

What I wanna get is a list for each day from DayA till DayB of post status for end of date.

```
DayA = 2016-09-01
DayB = 2016-09-05
```

```sql
  post_id  | date        | status 
-----------+-------------+---------
         3 | 2016-09-01  | null          
         3 | 2016-09-02  | 1         
         3 | 2016-09-03  | 1  
         3 | 2016-09-04  | 2  
         3 | 2016-09-05  | 2   
         6 | 2016-09-01  | null  
         6 | 2016-09-02  | null 
         6 | 2016-09-03  | 1 
         6 | 2016-09-04  | 2 
         6 | 2016-09-05  | 2
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

solution was found here: [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2010-10-01'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2010-10-05')
);

foreach ($period as $each){
   //.. QUERY here, where "CREAtED_AT" = $each
}
```

Comment: some sql solution?

Comment: about sql, i cant say. If you have the only way to do that using sql, that in my mind comes only the manual way to create the sql which contains all dates in the query, and that can be done automatically using javascript bookmarks, to fill the SQL input field with the correct SQL command.  but you need to do some more research in that case, to get code like: `javascript:function(){.....final =  date1 + date2...};` if you dont understand what i say, then you can disregard this my comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

For each post_id you want as many rows as there are days between the start and end date. This can be done by cross joining the list of dates with the post_ids and then join that result back to the table to get the status for each day:

```
select x.post_id, t.created, p.status
from generate_series(date '2016-09-01', date '2016-09-05', interval '1' day) as t(created)
  cross join (
     select distinct post_id 
     from post_status_changes
  ) x
  left join post_status_changes p on p.created_at::date = t.created
order by 1,2;
```

Running example: http://rextester.com/CSX38222

Comment: In results:
"3 03.09.2016 00:00:00 5"
This is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as 
    (select convert(varchar(10), created_at, 102) [date], [status], 
    post_id, rank() over (partition by convert(varchar(10), created_at), 
    post_id order by created_at desc) as r 
    from post_status_changes)
select post_id, [date], [status] from a where r = 
    (select top 1 r from a as a2 where a.[date] = 
    a2.[date] and a.[post_id] = a2.[post_id])
    and @DayA <= [date] and @DayB >= [date] order by post_id, [date];
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres (there is no `convert()` function, and square brackets are invalid in an identifier). You should at least use standard SQL for a question tagged with `sql`

Comment: And how does it generate the rows for 2016-09-01 or 2016-09-05 which are not present in the table?

Comment: Since I am new to answering questions on stack overflow, I overlooked that this was categorized under the postgresql tag. I was using T-SQL and also neglected to generate the series where the elements are not in the table. I found information on generating a series in T-SQL here, just in case anyone is interested, even though I should be answering questions according to the tag they are categorized under: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1