# Result not appropriate when generate Date

Tags: php, date, generated-code

```
$date_from = @$_REQUEST['Start'];   
$date_from = strtotime($date_from); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp
$date_to = @$_REQUEST['Finish'];   
$date_to = strtotime($date_to);
$day = 86400;

for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) 
{  
   echo date("Y-m-d",$i);
}
```

I encounter some problem with this code. Basically this code run well, but when you fill value $date_from = '2016-10-28' AND value $date_to = '2016-11-03', The Result appear in my screen :

> 2016-10-28
>   
>  2016-10-29
>   
>  2016-10-30
>   
>  2016-10-30
>   
>  2016-10-31
>   
>  2016-11-01
>   
>  2016-11-02

When it was supposed to be :

> 2016-10-28
>   
>  2016-10-29
>   
>  2016-10-30
>   
>  2016-10-31
>   
>  2016-10-01
>   
>  2016-11-02
>   
>  2016-11-03

Is there's error on my code or ? Because i have tried with different range but, everything went fine. Only this range of date appear like this.

Need Help.

Comment: Use `DateTime` with `DateInterval` https://secure.php.net/DateInterval

Comment: Try to get dates between two dates like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array

Comment: Daylight Savings... not every day has 86400 seconds