# How can we split dates in php?

Tags: php

How can we split dates using PHP? Is there any built in function in PHP?

```
2016-11-01 10:00:00 till 2016-11-03 18:00:00
```

I need to split above date in to required dates:-

```
2016-11-01 10:00:00 till 23:59:59
2016-11-02 00:00:00 till 23:59:59
2016-11-03 00:00:00 till 18:00:00
```

Comment: from where `23:59:59` this comes from?

Comment: @Anant It comes from calendar.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4312439/3933332 as a start

Comment: I just wonder why was it downvoted it's a perfecly legit question.

Comment: @Ace_Gentile, I also wondered too. I downvoted the answer below this though.

Comment: @samsam  check the answers below and mark+up-vote one answer (which is clear and correct to you). You need to up-vote others also if they are useful.Thanks.

Comment: Because @Ace_Gentile, it doesn't show research, and it appears as though it's a "dump and run" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge PHP does not provide such built-in feature.

But you can easily achieve this with th `DateTime` object :

```
$interval = '2016-11-01 10:00:00 till 2016-11-03 18:00:00';
$dates = explode(' till ', $interval);

if(count($dates) == 2) {
    $current = $begin = new DateTime($dates[0]);
    $end = new DateTime($dates[1]);

    $intervals = [];

    // While more than 1 day remains
    while($current->diff($end)->format('%a') >= 1) {

        $nextDay = clone $current;
        $nextDay->setTime(23,59,59);

        $intervals []= [
            'begin' => $current->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'end'   => $nextDay->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
        $current = clone $nextDay;
        $current->setTime(0,0,0);
        $current->modify('+1 day');
    }

    // Last interval : from $current to $end
    $intervals []= [
        'begin' => $current->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'end'   => $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];

    print_r($intervals);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use for loop to achieve such type of result. Your requirement is to print date in one day difference between start and end date. I have write code for this .

```
<?php
$startDate = strtotime('2016-11-01 10:00:00');
$endDate = strtotime('2016-11-03 18:00:00');

for ($loopStart = $startDate; $loopStart <= $endDate; $loopStart = strtotime('+1 day', $loopStart)) {

    // check last date
    if($endDate >= strtotime('+1 day', $loopStart)){
      echo  date('Y-m-d', $loopStart).' 23:59:59';
    }
    else{
      echo  date('Y-m-d', $loopStart).' '.date('H:i:s',$endDate);
    }

    echo "<br>";

}

?>
```

The output of the code is  -

```
2016-11-01 23:59:59
2016-11-02 23:59:59
2016-11-03 18:00:00
```

Comment: If i added `$startDate = strtotime('2016-11-28 07:58:18');
    $endDate   = strtotime('2016-11-29 07:58:18'); ` The result I am getting is  `2016-11-28 07:58:18<br>2016-11-29 07:58:18<br>`. In this case this is not correct.

Comment: For this case we need to update the >= in if statement. Just update the if conditions as if($endDate >= strtotime('+1 day', $loopStart)){