# Disponibility (disable days) in residential system using database(mysql,php)

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

I have a booking system from a residential and I can disable days specific but not days from my table with the days registered.
I have 2 tables `habitaciones` and `reservas`

```
table habitaciones  (room)
id_habitacion integer..

 table `reservas` (bookings)
`id_reserva integer`
 id_habitacion   integer
`llegada date`     (startdate)
`salida date`       (enddate)
```

I have input from `llegada` and `salida`

```
<input style="height: 31px;" id="datepicker2" class="form-control" name="llegada">
<input style="height: 31px;" id="datepicker3" class="form-control" name="salida">
```

In the script datepicker I have:

```
<script>
var disableddates = ["12-12-2016", "13-12-2016", "14-12-2016", "14-12-2016"];

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });
}); 
</script>
```

This its work:
[Disable days ["12-12-2016", "13-12-2016", "14-12-2016", "14-12-2016"]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMlrL.jpg)

Now I have dates from table `reservas` 
[select * from reservas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Qg4.jpg)

And I Finally need rescue this dates from table `reservas` and disabled days
between `llegada` and `salida` (where id_habitacion ....)(my english is more or less)

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I need the days disables from my database not from this code :var disableddates = ["12-12-2016", "13-12-2016", "14-12-2016", "14-12-2016"]; 
I do not know how take dates from table reservas, and this dates put disables

Comment: have you tried some PHP / SQL to do that ? if yes, put it on your question please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll probably help you to do what you want :

[PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

```
// add a $pdo link here

$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT llegada, salida 
    FROM reservas 
    WHERE id_habitacion = :id');

$req->execute(array('id'=>$id));

$data = $req->fetch();

$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($data['llegada']),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($data['salida'])
);

$arrDates = iterator_to_array($period);
$arrDates[] = $data['salida']; // add the last date
$dates = '['.implode(',', $aDates).']';
```