# Range from Y-m-d to current date

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get range of dates in php that will start from 2000-01-01 to current date in this format Year-Month-Day

I try this with no luck.

```
range(2000-01-01,date("Y-m-d"))
```

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17531045/3799829