# Insert date in one year automatically

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Help me please...

I want to insert all dates and days name in one year automatically.
for example : 2017. I want to insert into table from 01-01-2017 to 31-12-2017 automatically.

Comment: Probably use something like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4312491/2518525) and loop over the returned data, then insert it into your database.

Comment: Thx for the link. But How to modify that code if I input only the year in the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP way to do this:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2017-01-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-01-01');

while($startDate < $endDate){
    echo $startDate->format('d-m-Y'); //print date with format day-month-year
    echo "\n";
    $startDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //add 1 day
}
```

Output:

```
01-01-2017
02-01-2017
03-01-2017
04-01-2017
...
31-12-2017
```

Comment: I want to give the days name beside the date.

<?php
$startDate = new DateTime('2017-01-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-01-01');

$day = date('l');

while($startDate < $endDate){
 echo $startDate->format('d-m-Y'); //print date with format day-month-year
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
 echo $day;
 echo "<br>";
    $startDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //add 1 day
}
?>

Why the output is always "Thursday"? 
Help me please..

Comment: sorry for late response, could you message me directly via skype: hienboy90

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

with getFullYear().

```js
for (var d = new Date(2017, 0, 1); d < new Date(2018, 0, 1); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  var input = $("<input>");
  input.val(d.getFullYear());
  $("#year").append(input);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year">

</div>
```

Comment: How to modify that code if I input only the year in the textfield

Comment: @st.anger you can use getFullYear() to get just year from date.