# How to Get Remaining Date in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to get remaining date in PHP. For example, I would like to get date list from 2017-07-01 to 2017-08-10

So, I would like the output going to be like this

```
2017-07-01
2017-07-02
2017-07-03
2017-07-04
......
2017-08-10
```

How could I do that anyway? Thank you

Comment: Search before posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code for you: https://eval.in/842849

You should use `DatePeriod` which takes *`start-date, date interval, and end-date`* as arguments.

You will get the result object, which you can loop thru to get the desired dates between the 2 dates:

```
<?php
$begin = new DateTime('2017-07-01 ');
$end = new DateTime('2017-08-10');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at the [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php%22DatePeriod%22) class:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2010-10-01'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2010-10-05')
);
```

Which should get you an array with DateTime objects.