# Show dates between two dates

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a leave system where user select dates *`from`* and *`to`* dates let say `2018-02-26` - `2018-03-03` that is 6 days in total. On our portal it shows all users that is on leave. supposing that this user applied for 6 days leave, How am I going to display this user for 6 days on our portal?below is my code it works well but is show only for the current date.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

$lf = Leave::where('leave_from', $currentDate)
                       ->where('status', 'approved')
                       ->get();
```

I am using eloquent. thanks

Comment: [Possible duplicate of "PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datetime function in PHP.

```
$first_date = new DateTime($currentDate);

$last_date = new DateTime($if);

$difference = $first_date->diff($last_date);

echo $difference->d.' days;
```

if you want month and year use `$difference->m` and `$difference->y`.And if you want accurate days even dates are negative use below one.

```
$result = $first_date->diff($last_date)->format("%r%a");
```

source:/ [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: did you check this? @zluj

Comment: @lalitkumar thanks but how about on the next day what query should I use?

Comment: every day the current date is getting updated know..what you mean next day?

Comment: on my table I have this fields `leave_from` and `leave_end` let say leave from has a value of `2018-02-26` and leave end is `2018-03-03` so that is 6 days right?I want to display this on my page for 6 days.

Comment: you can fetch the leave_from and leave_end from DB and give it as $currentdate and $if then you will get the $result..You can show the $result wherever you want.

Answer (score 3):

```html
// Specify the start date. This date can be any English textual format  
$date_from = "2018-02-03";   
$date_from = strtotime($date_from); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  
  
// Specify the end date. This date can be any English textual format  
$date_to = "2018-02-10";  
$date_to = strtotime($date_to); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  
  
// Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates inbetween  
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {  
    echo date("Y-m-d", $i).'<br />';  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mohini.. but on the next day how am I going to query from db since the date stored is only date_from and date_to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_diff() function:

```
$interval = date_diff($currentDate, $lf);
echo $interval->format('%d');
```

more on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php; https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp) to get difference directly from query.

```
Select abs(DATEDIFF(`date_to`,`date_from`)) as diff from leaves;
```

In laravel you can write it as

```
$lf = Leave::where('status', 'approved')
      ->select(DB::raw("abs(DATEDIFF(`date_to`,`date_from`)) as diff"),"*")
      ->get();
```

Be sure to use `where('leave_from', $currentDate)`, I think it's not necessary.

Comment: Hello @C2486, I am using eloquent outside laravel so DB::raw got me an error.

Comment: @zluj : what you just need to use above first query

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime function of PHP
in your case

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$currentDate = new DateTime($currentDate);
$leaveDate = new DateTime($leaveFrom);
$difference = $currentDate->diff($leaveDate);
```

You will get result like

```
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 5 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 5 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                      $many_days=0;
                $date_from = "2018-02-26";      
                  $date_to = "2018-03-03";    
                for ($i=strtotime($date_from);   $i<=strtotime($date_to);  
                     $i+=86400) {  

                       $many_days++;
                         } 

              echo  "leaves $many_days";
```