# How can i get an array with last 7 dates?

Tags: php

I need to get an array with all dates of the last week - for example, if it is 02.06.2018 today, i have to get 02.06, 01.06, 31.05, 30.05, 29.05, 28.05, 27.05. It must consider month number and amount of days in the month. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Please check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array ...and replace the dates to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){

$myDates[] = date('d.m', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' - ' . $i . ' days'));

}

print_r($myDates);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks!