# How do I find the days between two dates in an array

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-range

I have an array with start date and end date. Now I want to save the individual days between the given days in an array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2019-02-16
        [end] => 2019-02-23
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2019-03-15
        [end] => 2019-03-17
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2019-03-23
        [end] => 2019-03-24
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2019-03-27
        [end] => 2019-03-29
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2019-04-17
        [end] => 2019-04-21
    )
)
```

That should be the result: (only the days in "between")

```
Array
( 
 '2019-03-16',
 '2019-03-28',
 '2019-04-18',
 '2019-04-19',
 '2019-04-20'
)
```

How can I loop through the array?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually u are saying date u need date between 2 dates, like `[start] => 2019-03-23
        [end] => 2019-03-24` u have 0 days bw these 2 dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

Apply this to each couple of dates and merge into array:

```
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-02-16');
$from->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-02-23');
$dates = iterator_to_array( new \DatePeriod( $from ), new \DateInterval( 'P1D' ), $to ) );
```

Comment: its also included `2019-02-16`

Comment: Add a day then, let me edit.

Comment: perfect @ Elanochecer

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I do not know how I can apply this to my array

Comment: You just have to iterate over your array and set 'from' and 'to' with the 'start' and 'end' dates of your array.